# Autonumbering Flutter TabBar tabs

Tags: flutter, tabbar

Starting with https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs, how can I make the tabs in the TabBar display their index please?

Note I can't pass the index number into each Tab() in step 2 of the above article

Instead, I would like each Tab to take care of finding its own index. Maybe by searching back up the widget tree to find the parent TabController (which will have a child containing the list of tabs) and then search for itself in that list to determine its own index.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class that extends Tab class and pass index in constructor. Then you could create tabs like:

```
tabs: List.generate(3, (int index) => index).map((i) => MyTab(index = i),
```

or you could create tabs manually

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in the question, I am wondering whether there's a way for the Tab to discover its own index rather than having it passed into the constructor